# Elemento mas repetido JavaScript

Tags: javascript, array, objeto

necesito ayuda para encontrar el elemento mas repetido dentro de un arreglo de objetos, lo hice usando un for anidado, pero la respuesta no coincide con el elemento esperado.

```js
const users = [{
    name: 'Georg',
    id: 23,
  },
  {
    name: 'Andrea',
    id: 23,
  },
  {
    name: 'Luis',
    id: 25,
  },
  {
    name: 'Daniela',
    id: 23,
  },
  {
    name: 'Manuel',
    id: 27,
  },
  {
    name: 'Lucas',
    id: 25,
  },
];

function findRepeatedAge(users) {
  let result = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
    for (let j = i + 1; j < users.length; j++) {
      if (users[i]["id"] === users[j]["id"]) {
        result = users[i]["id"]
      }
    }
  }
  return result;
}
console.log(findRepeatedAge(users));
```

La respuesta que me da es 25, y busco un 23 que es el id que mas se repite.

Comment: ¿Que pasa si dos o más ids se repiten la misma cantidad de veces? ¿Que esperas en ese caso como resultado?

Comment: el que se repite mas veces

Comment: No has respondido a la pregunta de @JaimeMenéndez. ¿Qué ocurre si dos `id` se repiten el mismo número de veces? Por otro lado, tu código solo encuentra la última coincidencia de parejas, porque solo estás comparando parejas. Para hacer lo que quieres debes almacenar la cuenta. Redacto respuesta.

Comment: @OscarGarcia Habrá una cantidad mayor y una menor, y de repetirse varios id la misma cantidad de veces retornaría cualquiera de ellos. Ahora si almaceno los repetidos en un nuevo array, se cuenta uno demás. Es por eso que hice la consulta.

Comment: Te he redactado una respuesta en el que aparecerá el primer valor más alto encontrado.

Answer (score 2):

Si quieres, puedes hacerlo todo en un mismo loop, pero con la misma idea que OscarGarcia en su respuesta.

Tienes un objeto que hace seguimiento del número de veces que aparece cada elemento, en cada iteración puedes comprobar si el más repetido ha cambiado.

```js
const users = [
  {
    name: 'Georg',
    id: 23,
  },
  {
    name: 'Andrea',
    id: 23,
  },
  {
    name: 'Luis',
    id: 25,
  },
  {
    name: 'Daniela',
    id: 23,
  },
  {
    name: 'Manuel',
    id: 27,
  },
  {
    name: 'Lucas',
    id: 25,
  },
];
const contador = {};
let vecesMasRepetido = 0;
let idMasRepetido = null;

users.forEach(({ id }) => {
  contador[id] = (contador[id] ?? 0) + 1;
  if (contador[id] > vecesMasRepetido) {
    idMasRepetido = id;
    vecesMasRepetido = contador[id];
  }
});

console.log(`ID más repetido: ${idMasRepetido}. Aparece ${vecesMasRepetido} veces.`);
console.log(`Objeto contador: ${JSON.stringify(contador)}`);
```

- `contador` hace seguimiento de cada id y cuántas veces aparece.
- `vecesMasRepetido` almacena cuantas veces aparece el que más se ha repetido.
- `idMasRepetido` almacena el id que más se ha repetido.

`users.forEach` hace una iteración por cada elemento de la lista `users`. Y como solo usamos la propiedad `id` de cada elemento, usamos la [sintaxis de destructuración](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) para sacar solo ese valor ya directamente en una variable. Así, en lugar de usar `users.forEach(elemento => elemento.id)`, podemos hacer `users.forEach(({ id }) => id)`.

En el loop por cada id de `users`:

1. `contador[id] = (contador[id] ?? 0) + 1;` Si contador[id] existe, lo coge y suma 1, si no existe, coge el 0 y suma 1.
2. `if (contador[id] > vecesMasRepetido)` comprueba si el id que estoy comprobando ahora ya es el mas repetido.
3. Si lo es, actualizo `idMasRepetido` con el id que más se repite hasta ahora, y actualizo `vecesMasRepetido` con el numero de veces que más se repite un id hasta ahora.

Comment: Pregunta: porque encierras el id con llaves en la función forEach?, podría explicar eso por favor.

Comment: es una interpolacion

Comment: @AngelVera es la [sintaxis de destructuración](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment). Así puedo acceder directamente a una variable llamada `id` con el valor `id` de cada objeto, en lugar de tener que acceder como `elemento.id`. He actualizado la respuesta añadiendo esa información y enlace.

Comment: Por favor podrías explicar un poco el elemento contador[id], se que contador es el objeto vacío pero la notación con corchetes con el id, ¿Qué tipo de método es?.

Comment: @AngelVera contador es un objeto como tú dices. La notación en corchete permite acceder a las propiedades de un objeto de forma programática. Para acceder a las propiedades de un objeto puedes hacerlo de varias formas. Ej: `const obj = { 'a': 1, 'b': 2 }`. Para acceder a la propiedad "a" puedes hacer `obj.a`, o `obj['a']`. Si tienes una variable `const prop = 'a'`, ahora puedes acceder haciendo `obj[prop]`, pero si haces `obj.prop` el resultado sería `undefined` porque intentaría acceder a la propiedad "prop", que no existe.

Comment: Gracias, ya lo entendí completamente,  justo estaba probando eso del obj.prop y me daba undefined, ahora ya lo entiendo mejor.

Answer (score 2):

Yo lo haria asi:

Primero convierto el arreglo de usuarios en arreglo de ids con `map` para mejorar el performance.
Luego buscamos cada uno de los elementos como para tenerlo en arreglitos usando `find`.
Luego sacamos la cantidad de elementos de cada arreglito con `length`.
Ordenamos en base a esa cantidad de elementos con `sort`.
Y finalmente obtenemos el elemento con mas entradas mediante `pop`.

A partir de el segundo punto se puede hacer en una sola linea usando el enfoque de [programacion funcional](https://javapro.org/programming-languages/programar-javascript-formas-de-pensar/)

```
ids.sort((a, b) => ids.filter(v => v == a).length - ids.filter(v => v == b).length).pop().
```

### Ejemplo completo en codigo

```js
const users = [{
    name: 'Georg',
    id: 23,
  },
  {
    name: 'Andrea',
    id: 23,
  },
  {
    name: 'Luis',
    id: 25,
  },
  {
    name: 'Daniela',
    id: 23,
  },
  {
    name: 'Manuel',
    id: 27,
  },
  {
    name: 'Lucas',
    id: 25,
  },
];

function findRepeatedAge(users) {
  let ids = users.map(user => user.id) // calculos en un arreglo de enteros es mas rapido que en un arreglo de objetos
  return ids.sort( // ordena de dos en dos
    (id1, id2) => // primer id a comparar, segundo id a comparar
    ids.filter(valor => valor == id1).length // veces que aparece id1
    -
    ids.filter(valor => valor == id2).length //veces que aparecer id2
  ).pop() // saca al primero que halles que tenga mas apariciones
}
console.log(findRepeatedAge(users));
```

Esto si solo necesitas el numero como en tu pregunta, si necesitas mostrar algo te recomiendo pasarlo primero a una estructura tipo clave valor por ejemplo con

```js
const users = [{
    name: 'Georg',
    id: 23,
  },
  {
    name: 'Andrea',
    id: 23,
  },
  {
    name: 'Luis',
    id: 25,
  },
  {
    name: 'Daniela',
    id: 23,
  },
  {
    name: 'Manuel',
    id: 27,
  },
  {
    name: 'Lucas',
    id: 25,
  },
];
let grouped = users.reduce(
  (acc, user) => { // acumulador, usuario
    acc[user.id] = acc[user.id] || []; //ponemos la clave
    acc[user.id].push(user); // le ponemos el valor
    return acc; // regresamos el objeto
  }, Object.create(null) // nuestro punto inicial es crear un objeto {}
);

console.log(grouped)
```

Comment: Se ve conciso y es una solución totalmente válida y elegante en cuanto a código, pero teniendo en cuenta el rendimiento: La ordenación de por sí tiene complejidad(con los mejores algoritmos) de `O(nlogn)` pero si haces dos búsquedas lineales dentro de cada paso de cada comparación, se convierte en `O(n²log n)`, lo cual es un tiempo bastante malo teniendo en cuenta que lo puedes lograr en O(n) como lo planteó @Oscar o @ArianJM.

Answer (score 1):

Deberías dividir el problema en dos partes:

- Contar el número de veces que se repite un `id`.
- Obtener el `id` que más veces estaba repetido.

Esto lo puedes conseguir como muestro a continuación:

```js
const users = [
  { name: 'Georg', id: 23 },
  { name: 'Andrea', id: 23 },
  { name: 'Luis', id: 25 },
  { name: 'Daniela', id: 23 },
  { name: 'Manuel', id: 27 },
  { name: 'Lucas', id: 25 },
];

/* Contamos el número de veces que cada "id" se repite */
function countId(users) {
  let result = {};
  users.forEach(element => {
    /* Si aún no lo tenemos contabilizado lo creamos con un 1 */
    if (result.hasOwnProperty(element.id)) {
      result[element.id]++;
    } else {
      result[element.id] = 1;
    }
  });
  return result;
}

/* Obtenemos aquél "id" que esté más veces repetido */
function getMaxId(ids) {
  /* En un principio no hay ni máximo ni "id" */
  let max = undefined, maxId = undefined;
  /* Iteramos todas las propiedades del objeto */
  for (const id in ids) {
    /* Si aún no tenemos máximo o éste es mayor que el anterior */
    if (max === undefined || ids[id] > max) {
      /* Asignamos el nuevo máximo y almacenamos qué "id" era */
      max = ids[id];
      maxId = id;
    }
  }
  return maxId;
};

/* Obtenemos la cuenta de "id" */
const count = countId(users);
/* Mostramos cuál se repitió más veces */
console.log(getMaxId(count));
```